# Winforms, databinding, Listbox and textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a ListBox (`MyListBox`) on my screen, and a Textbox (`MyTextBox`).

The ListBox is filled with a List(Of T), which are all custom items.

Now I try to do this:

The ListBox' datasource is the List(Of T).

Now when an Item changes I want the textbox to be updated to a particular property of the selected item in my ListBox.

In code this means:

```
Me.MyListBox.DisplayMember = "SelectionName"
Me.MyListBox.ValueMember = "Id"

MyTextbox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me._listOfItems, "SelectedItem.Comment", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

Me.MyListBox.DataSource = Me._listOfItems
```

this does not work. But when I bind to SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem it works perfectly.

The `_listOfItems` is declared as this:

```
Dim _listOfItems As List(Of MyItem) = New List(Of MyItem)()
```

Where `MyItem` is this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string SelectionName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I tried overriding the `ToString()` in `MyItem` so that it would use that. But that doesn't work either.

Anybody care to give it a try?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the easiest way, I guess, would be to use a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx), setting it as the [`ListBox.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property to your `BindingSource` on design.

1. Drop a `BindingSource` on your form;
2. Set your `ListBox.DataSource` property to your `BindingSource`;
3. Set your `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties just like you're actually doing;
4. Make your `DataBinding` for your `TextBox` control, and use your `BindingSource` as the source, using your `MyItem.Comment` property;
5. Assign your `List(Of MyItem)` to your `Binding.DataSource` property;
6. Your TextBox should follow the `CurrencyManager.CurrentItem`'s Comment property, that is, the currently `ListBox.SelectedItem`.

Indeed, you would perhaps need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface to make it work properly.

But if this all work perfect with the SelectValue, why don't you just use it?

Comment: The SelectedValue is the Id, I need the comment. And I can't use that to call to the database :) I'll try your solution!

Comment: I got it! You're right, if what you want is to offer a choice selection to the user, let's not do it with the Id. =P

Comment: option 5 is not needed :) and for option 4: I use this binding:

new Binding("Text", bindingSource1, "Comment", ...) since it already uses the .Current property of the bindingSource!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how I am doing it.  I first set my ListBox DataSource to a class with a collection of BindingList.  The class implements IBindingList.  I have two TextBoxes I want to bind the SelectedItem to.  The code below is how I am doing it:

```
lbControl.DataSource = SharepointTestBusinessLayer.Control.ListAll();
lbControl.DisplayMember = "ControlName";
lbControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
scTextBoxControlID.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.lbControl.DataSource, "ControlID");
scTextBoxControlName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.lbControl.DataSource, "ControlName");
```