# Event will not fire upon listbox item selection - .Net UIAutomation framework

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am learning the .NET UI Automation framework today. So what i have done so far (referring to various articles)

1. Have a WinForm with Listbox, PictureBox, TextBox and Button controls on it. Refer to picture please: [image: WinForm to be tested]
2. I have a consoleapp which is having all UI Automation test scripts or code which automates the winform UI testing.

**Working:**
Upon selecting the item from listbox, the picture box loads some image and displays it (the code to load is in SelectedIndexChanged event of listbox).

Below is the code of the Forms listBox control:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        pictureBox1.Image = imageCollection.ElementAtOrDefault(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        textBox1.Text = pictureBox1.Image.GetHashCode().ToString();
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

Now my UIAutomation test script code is like below: (Only necessary part is shown)

```
        AutomationElement listBoxElement = mainFormWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "listBox1"));

        Assert.IsNotNull(listBoxElement, "Cant find the listbox element");

        AutomationElementCollection listBoxItems = 
            listBoxElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children,new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty,ControlType.ListItem));

        AutomationElement itemToSelectInListBox = listBoxItems[new Random().Next(0, listBoxItems.Count - 1)];

        Object selectPattern = null;

        if (itemToSelectInListBox.TryGetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern, out selectPattern))
        {
            (selectPattern as SelectionItemPattern).AddToSelection();
            (selectPattern as SelectionItemPattern).Select();

        }
```

After executing the code, the Select() method does works and the Form listbox item gets selected as shown
: [image]

As you can see in the image, the listbox item is getting selected but the event SelectedIndexChange isnt getting fired and the picturebox is not reflecting the change.

So any pointers is of great help :)

Thanks

Comment: I dont know what the problem is, but you can have a temporary workaround by adding `listbox1_selectedIndexChanged(null,null);` after the statement `AutomationElement itemToSelectInListBox = listBoxItems[new Random().Next(0, listBoxItems.Count - 1)];
`

Comment: As i said, this Automation UI APIs are in a consoleapp (another project and exe) and the Form is on another. The only way i can do as you said is by using relfection api. But if i do that, it will be totally diff instance and no connection at all.

Answer (score 1):

@zenwalker
Is the list populated by data binding? If yes, there is a chance selection events don't fire. Can you share the code that binds data to the listbox? Apologies for putting this in answer, I don't have enough reps to add comments.

Alternately you can refer to the following SO article to see how we can do databinding to listbox [Winforms, databinding, Listbox and textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904682/winforms-databinding-listbox-and-textbox)

Comment: Nope, i have added the content of listbox at design time itself manually. So i have not used any databinding context here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works if SelectionMode is changed to MultiSimple. I am not sure why this happens.
But if the SelectionMode is One, the selectedindexevent is not fired.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little too late, but I still hope this will be helpful for someone:

I had the exact same problem. Was able to trigger the event by a mouse click. For the following code, you will need a reference to Microsoft.TestAPI (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestApi/0.6.0), but there are other ways to simulate a click as well.

```
    static AutomationElement SelectItem(AutomationElement item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            ((SelectionItemPattern)item.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern)).Select();
            System.Windows.Point point = item.GetClickablePoint();
            Microsoft.Test.Input.Mouse.MoveTo(new System.Drawing.Point((int)point.X, (int)point.Y));
            Microsoft.Test.Input.Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left);
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the event `SelectedIndexChanged` is not fired while the `SelectionMode` is set to single or one.

Make sure that you update the PictureBox also while the `SelectionChanged` event is fired