# How do I update item quantity in shopping basket when an item is added in to the listbox in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a shopping basket application in C# at the moment.

Is there a way that when I press the add button it can update the item quantity each time that an item is added to the basket?

Thanks. This is my current code:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 100;
    NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 0;
    textBox5.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    if (NumericUpDown1.Value == 0) 
    { 
        NumericUpDown1.Value = +1;
    }
}
```

[As I've added two items to the basket the quantity should change to 2 but it doesn't it just stays at 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49AgO.png)

Comment: Include code instead for this image

Comment: Why should quantity be two? There is only one test 1 product, and isn't that what it's displaying the quatntiy of? No. items is 2. Is this not correct behavior?

Comment: add code, not screenshots. Listbox can have a count property .ListBox1.Items.Count which returns the amount of items listbox currently holds.

Comment: protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
            NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 100;
            NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 0;
            textBox5.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();


            if (NumericUpDown1.Value == 0)
            {
                NumericUpDown1.Value = +1;
            }

Comment: If I add another to the list and there's more than one item then the quantity is suppose to update according to the number of items in the listbox.

Comment: If I add an item and it will say one item is in there. Then if I add another item the quantity will stay at 1 instead of increasing to 2 as that is the number of items that will be in the basket at the time.

Comment: What I mean is whenever I enter an item in the ProductName textbox it adds it to the list which will have the quantity say 1. I want to be able to add another item in the same textbox after which will then update the quantity to say 2. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would keep a list of objects that store product name/description and value (count) using the product name as the key. Then I'd use databinding to bind the list to the listbox and let databinding do the work of displaying any updates.

The idea being that you can find the object you're interested in by searching your list, then update it's "quantity" property, leaving databinding to update the UI.

Alternatively, you could use the new class you create to add directly to the listbox, but set the ValueMember and DisplayMember properties accordingly.

```
public class OrderLineViewModel 
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public uint Quantity { get; set; }        
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904834/26414) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904682/winforms-databinding-listbox-and-textbox) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I will give this is a go now.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code, based on the comments:

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
      NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 100;
      NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 0;

      int previousNoItems;
      Int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out previousNoItems);
      textBox5.Text += previousNoItems + NumericUpDown1.Value;
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between "quantity" and "no items"?

Comment: The quantity is similar as I would need to use that to get the final price of the no items that will be in the basket.

Comment: When you add new item with quantity n (corresponds to NumericUpDown1.Value), total number of items 
(textBox5.Text) shall increase by n, right?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I want to do .

Comment: I recommend to use the solution that Neil is suggesting, otherwise you lose trace between items its quantities. Unless you need to replicate the items based on the quantity and perform  listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text); multiple times.