# WinForm Databound Control Results Return Class Name Not Actual Data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I am having a very hard time finding a solution to my issue.  I have scoured the Internet, rebuilt my class several times, and have gone through every line in the debugger.

I have three ListBox controls that I am databinding a BindingList to.  In two of the ListBoxes, the data is what is expected; names from the database.  The third ListBox does not display names, but the namespace of the items.  In each of my classes I have implemented the IBindingList interface.  I have bound the list to the DataSource of the control and supplied the appropriate name for the DisplayMember.

In the debugger, I can see the names from the database in the lbRole ListBox after they are bound to the DataSource, but when the form displays they don't appear, just the namespace.

```
//
// Get all control names.
//
lbUser.DataSource = SharepointTestBusinessLayer.User.ListAll();
lbUser.DisplayMember = "LoginID";

lbControl.DataSource = SharepointTestBusinessLayer.Control.ListAll();
lbControl.DisplayMember = "ControlName";

lbRole.DataSource = SharepointTestBusinessLayer.Role.ListAll();
lbRole.DisplayMember = "RoleName";
```

In walking through my classes with the debugger, in the RoleItemCollection class, GetEnumerator() is never hit.

```
BindingList<RoleItem> m_CurrentRoleItemCollection;

public BindingList<RoleItem> CurrentRoleItemCollection { get => m_CurrentRoleItemCollection; set => m_CurrentRoleItemCollection = value; }

public object this[int index] { get => ((IBindingList)CurrentRoleItemCollection)[index]; set => ((IBindingList)CurrentRoleItemCollection)[index] = value; }

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IBindingList)CurrentRoleItemCollection).GetEnumerator();
}
```

I don't know why GetEnumerator() is never his in the RoleItemCollection class as it is hit in the ControlItemCollection and UserItemCollection classes.

Does anything come to mind with this issue you might have some insight into.  I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: Does `RoleItemCollection` class implement `IEnumerable`?

Comment: No, RoleItemCollection does not implement IEnumerable.  Neither does UserItemCollection or ControlItemCollection and I get expected results with those classes.

Comment: Can you please share the source of ListAll()? It doesn't seem to be a method of IBindingList.

Comment: In my business layer I have a static class called Role which is called from the form.  This is a static method ListAll() that returns a RoleItemCollection,  In this method, I call a DataLayer static class called Role which has a static method called ListAll().  This method connects with Sql Server, calls a stored procedure, and uses a DataReader for fetching data.  I put the data into a RoleItem class which I then add to the RoleItemCollection class. The RoleItemCollection class implements the BindingList<T>.

Comment: I've reproduced the problem. Can it be that the RoleItem class does not have a property with the name `RoleName`? Because, according to your code, I implemented a RoleItem class and put a RoleName property in it and it worked (displayed "Admin" etc in the list box). Then I changed the property name to RoleName2 and the type name of the class was displayed in the list. Please check if you really have a property named `RoleName` in class `RoleItem`.

Comment: Thanks so very much for digging into this with me.  Here is my RoleItem class:

public class RoleItem : Common Base
{
 #region Members
 int? m_RoleID;
 string m_RolelName;
 #endregion

 #region Properties
 public int? RoleID { get => m_RoleID; set => m_RoleID = value; }
 public string RolelName { get => m_RolelName; set => m_RolelName = value; }
 #endregion

 public RoleItem(int RoleID, string RolelName)
 {
  try
  {
   this.RoleID = RoleID;
   this.RolelName = RolelName;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw();
   throw;
  }
 }
}

Comment: This is still a mystery to me.  I added a field to my Role table called NameOfRole and used it as the DataMember of the bound control and it worked!  For some reason RoleName was not liked.  Still working on this.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449779/172769) was proposed here as a solution. I am preserving the link here in case the answer here is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out part of the reason for this.  When I changed the property name from RoleName to NameOfRole, I got actual data.  I don't know why this would be but RoleName as the actual name of the property was in conflict with something I have yet to find.  Thank you everyone who took the time to answer my question.