# How to retrieve data from SQL into a textbox using Binding?

Tags: c#

This is my Model:

```
public class ComplaintModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string ValuesFromSalesOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return  CustomerName;
        }
    }

}
```

This is where I run the query to get data from SQL:

```
    public class DataAccess
    {
        public List<ComplaintModel> FindOrderNumber(string _OrderNumber)
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
            {
                var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($"SELECT c.name FROM SalesOrder so JOIN Customer c ON so.customerID = c.id WHERE so.number = ' {_OrderNumber} '").ToList();
                return output;

            }
        }
     }
```

And finally, here I am trying to show the returned value from SQL to a TextBox...

```
public Complaints_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
   
}

private void UpdateBinding()
{
    customer_name.DataBindings.Add("Text", orderNumb, "ValuesFromSalesOrder"); // This is the textbox
}

List<ComplaintModel> orderNumb = new List<ComplaintModel>();

private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

    orderNumb = db.FindOrderNumber(orderNumber.Text);


    UpdateBinding();
}
```

**Question**

First attempt at clicking the `Search Button` - Nothing happens and the `CustomerName` text box does not get updated.

Second time I click the `Search Button` - I get this error: `System.ArgumentException: 'This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Parameter name: binding'`

I have tested the query in SQL Server - it definitely returns a value.

Where I'm I going wrong? And how do I make it work.

**Research**

I have used this answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Winforms, databinding, Listbox and textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904682/winforms-databinding-listbox-and-textbox)

Comment: You can start by reading the exception message.

Comment: @IanKemp Thank you - will have a read now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have noticed what the issue was.

Here:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
{
    var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($"SELECT c.name FROM SalesOrder so JOIN Customer c ON so.customerID = c.id WHERE so.number = ' {_OrderNumber} '").ToList();
    return output;
}
```

This specific part of the query: `SELECT c.name`

I needed to changed it to : `SELECT c.name as CustomerName` notice the extra part `as CustomerName`.

This then links in with my Model `public string CustomerName { get; set; }`.

Now it fully works.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a new binding every time the button gets clicked.  You should only add the binding once.  You don't update a binding when it's source value changes.  Once a binding is created then it will catch any changes to the object or value it's bound to and reflect that change as appropriate.

Add the binding in the form constructor, remove the `UpdateBinding` method and the call to it in the button click handler.  You'll also need to make `orderNumb` a field on the form instead of a private variable in the button click handler.